# Using Python async to compute things out of order

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm trying to understand async and it's getting confusing. Here's basically what I'm trying to do asynchronously:

```
def process_data(i):
    time.sleep(5) # something involving i/o that takes some time
    return random.randint(0,10)

def main():
    return [process_data(i) for i in range(100)]
```

I don't actually care about the order of the output in this case but I should probably know how to do ordered and unordered anyway.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ordered result, you could use [gather method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)

```
import asyncio
import random

async def process_data(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return random.randint(0,10)

async def main():
    tasks = [process_data(i) for i in range(100)]
    result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print(result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

For unordered result, it is depending on the situations